# Bandwidth control in LAN

Tags: networking, bandwidth, lan

I want to control the bandwidth used by each users in my LAN. We are using a Motorola cable modem with wifi to share internet. There is no option to do this in the modem. Please help me.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  As an aside, you probably can't

Comment: Probably? I think there must be a solution.

Comment: Your modem does not offer the functionality, and there is nothing your computer can do to prevent other computers from sending data.

Comment: What about creating a server that can do it and redirecting all traffic through it.

Comment: ask coding questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup a hotspot in one of your system and redirect all the traffic through the system. Now you can implement QOS in this system to do all the controlling you want.